# Getting GraphQL data into Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a working query within my playground. But unsure how to get that data into the page? Below is my working query.

Do I use `<p>{data.node.GitHub_Repository.name}</p>` to get the relevant data, I am looking to build something similar to the pinned repos on GitHub profile page for my personal site.

Tried a few things but always get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating....`

```
const PinnedRepos = () => {
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query{
        github {
          user(login: "mrpbennett") {
            pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
                edges {
                node {
                    ... on GitHub_Repository {
                    name
                    description
                    url
                    primaryLanguage {
                        name
                        color
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
      }
    `)

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{data.node.GitHub_Repository.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Playground Query is as follows:

```
query{
        github {
          user(login: "mrpbennett") {
            pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
                edges {
                node {
                    ... on GitHub_Repository {
                    name
                    description
                    url
                    primaryLanguage {
                        name
                        color
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't accessing the query data correctly. Also note that pinnedItems is defined as an array, so you must map over it and render the node names like below

```
return (
    <div>
        {data.github.user.pinnedItem.edges.map(({node}) => <p>{node.name}</p>)
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go, how could i build out a component that would incorperate all the items?

Comment: I’d like to display it so I can use to display in the same way as the GitHub pinned repos

Comment: Looping on the pinned items and rendering whatever content you want inside the map will help you achive that. Note that you can separate out the JSX returned from map into a separate component to make it more clear

Comment: hmm I have used your code example. I still get the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.github.user.pinnedItem.edges')` - yet i am still getting the results within the playground

Comment: @mrpbennett `pinnedItems`ssssssssssssss ... just follow your query structure prefixed with `data`

Comment: How can i access primaryLanguage? I have tried the following `{data.github.user.pinnedItems.edges.node.map(({primaryLanguage}) => (` but no luck.

Comment: primaryLanguage is part of node, you can access it similar to `node.name` in the above snippet like `node.primaryLanguage`